# Controllers creating correct routes so both work properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I currently have 2 controllers in my project. My navigation bar uses @Html.ActionLinks and I have the actionlink pick the action and the controller. For some reason the actions are correct but it doesn’t always choose the controller. So im guessing this is something to do with my roureconfig? I been trying to make it choose the correct controller or having it choose ether one wth {controller}/{action} but still I haven’t had any luck
I have a PartsController and a OrderStatusController. When I click on my parts actionlinks they all work, but when I click on my orderstatus action link it goes “parts”, “OrderIndex” even tho I have it specifically saying “OrderStatus”, “OrderIndex” any idea why here are some of my configs I tried?

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            //routes.MapRoute(
            //   name: "Default",
            //   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            //   defaults: new { controller., action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);



            // OrderStatus/{action}/{id}
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "OrderStatus",
            //    url: "{OrderStatus}/{action}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "OrderStatus", action = "OrderIndex", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);

            //// Parts/Index
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "Parts_Index",
            //    url: "{Parts}/{Index}/{id}",
            //    defaults: new { controller = "Parts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            //);

            // Parts/Index          (Home Page)
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Parts", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: This is a very handy tool for debugging MVC route issues - https://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/

Comment: add the view code to i can see how you have it.

Comment: defaults is what is use if nothing is passed as in "host:port/" so it will hit the Parts controlller and index. YOU should NOT have to setup any other route for what you describe to work. So i suggest include your view code, with the actionlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your OrderStatus route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "OrderStatus",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "OrderStatus", action = "Index"}
);
```

It needs to be above of the default route since the MVC framework evaluates the routes from top to bottom (the order matters here) that is also why you get to the Parts view when trying order status..